Draw a square from dimensions entered in a form in QGIS-QField
I have a project in QGIS, I created some forms to create and modify some objects (point, line, polygon).
When I draw a polygon, I always draw a square or rectangle, because I insert some manholes in the map, and in the form that appear after the draw I insert the real measure in meters.
Now I would that, after I insert all the data in the form, the square/rectangular assume the real dimension that I insert in the form in QField.
Here u can find the project:  https://files.fm/f/9xrpma3dzh

You can:
1 Create a point layer with the attributes you need, including width and height.
2 Style it using geometry generator:
bounds(collect_geometries(translate(geometry:=$geometry, dx:="width"/2, dy:="height"/2), translate(geometry:=$geometry, dx:=-"width"/2, dy:=-"height"/2)

The expression will create two points on either side of the center point at the distances specified in width/height field. Then create a minimum bounding rectangle around them.

And then, when you get back to the office, convert the layer to a polygon layer with Geometry By Expression.


Interesting.....I forgot to say that some of the manhole just exist in the layer, and they are polygons. When I found them I must misure the man hole and adjust the size of the rectangle on the map. Now I'm far out, far from my laptop. When I come back home I upload the project.
Actually I download the data, draw every single manhole on CAD and export it in QGIS. After I resize the polygon to the shape of CAD object..... :(

here the project:   https://files.fm/f/9xrpma3dzh
